# File input custom message HTML5 override issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display custom message when a submit button click and need to override HTML5 default message. I have written following code.

I am using following code in text box and it works fine but same code doesn't work in file upload input box

File input control behaves in a different way. When I submit button first time , there is no error message showing but when I click on second time it shows my custom message.

I am not able to understand why it doesn't show custom error message at first time.

Please help me. Thanks.

Sample Html:

```
<input type='text' class='common' required='true' title="custom message" value='' onkeyup = "this.setCustomValidity('');"/>

<input type='file' id="f1" required='true' title="custom message2"  class='common' onkeyup = "this.setCustomValidity('');" onchange="validate_fileupload(this);" />

<input type='file' id="f2"  required='true' title="custom message3"  class='common' onkeyup = "this.setCustomValidity('');" onchange="validate_fileupload(this);" />
```

JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    $('.common').on('invalid', function () {
        var textfield = $(this).get(0);


        if (textfield.value == "") {
            textfield.setCustomValidity('@Resources.Content.MF');
        } else {
            textfield.setCustomValidity('');
        }

    });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done like this. I have used **`setCustomValidity`** inside this fucntion instead of keyup and it works as expected

```
  function validate_fileupload(file) {

        file.setCustomValidity('');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you encapsulate your jQuery with a...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // Your code
});
```

To ensure that the DOM has loaded before you wire up events to it.

I'm not sure this will solve your issue, I feel like there isn't enough information to give more help if you're saying that it works the second time.

To further debug your issues please add the rest of the function dependecies in your code, or put some `console.log()` or `debuggers;` in that `invalid` listener to see what's happening.